# How to load items of Array in a ListBox? C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I have a CheckedListBox and when it is marked keep the options in an Array. I need that when you click on a "List" button, the elements of the Array (options marked the CheckListBox) are listed in the ListBox. It should look something like this:

```
CheckListBox:

[x] Option 1
[ ] Option 2
[ ] Option 3
[x] Option 4

Button OnClick results:

List Box:
Option 1
Option 2
```

Comment: There's probably an appropriate event you can bind to when an option item was clicked. Synchronize your ListBox when this event is received.

Comment: Also you should give a code sample of what you already have tried, and specify better where you are stuck in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the items in the checklistbox and use the `Checked` property to determine if an item is checked or not. In pseudo-code

```
for i = 0..myCheckListBox.Items.Count-1
  if (myCheckListBox.Checked[i]) then
    myList.Add(myCheckListBox.Items[i]);
```